# How to concatenate columns using group_by and summarize dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset "df1":

| sex | codfam | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 |
| 1 | 110 | 1 |
| 2 | 110 | 4 |
| 1 | 120 | 4 |
| 2 | 120 | 5 |

I use "group_by" and "summarize" for grouping the codfam according to the min value of column "Class"

```
df <- df1 %>% 
group_by(codfam) %>%
summarize(fam_class = min(class))
```

It works fine and return me a result like this:

| codfam | class |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 110 | 1 |
| 120 | 4 |

Now I would get the value of column "sex" related to every codfam that function "summarize" keep in the dataset, something like this:

| sex | codfam | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 110 | 1 |
| 2 | 120 | 4 |

I tried to use

```
   df <- df1 %>% 
   group_by(sex, codfam) %>%
   summarize(fam_class = min(class))
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on your data,  the codfam value of 120 and class 4 shows sex 1

Comment: It doesn't work how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`slice_min`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(codfam) %>%
  slice_min(n = 1, order_by = class) %>%
  ungroup
```